# Which methods do people use to understand queueing networks?

Tags: simulation, queueing, stochastic-approximation

Queueing networks can be analyzed through analytic results (in some cases), approximation methods or simulation (discrete-event simulation, system dynamics). Analytic solutions do not exist in general. Which method do you use and why?

Comment: Often a queueing system can be treated as a regenerative process, where the regeneration epochs are the times at which the system becomes empty and the cycles the busy cycles. This is one approach to consider when you believe that analytic results "do not exist."